# Itertools product without intermediate results

Tags: python, product, python-itertools

Given a list of X elements I need to generate a sequence of k-length.
if list= [1,2,3] and k=2 the result would be:

```
 ('1', '1')
 ('1', '2')
 ('1', '3')
 ('2', '1')
 ('2', '2')
 ('2', '3')
 ('3', '1')
 ('3', '2')
 ('3', '3')
```

The itertools.product(list,repeat=k-length) would work wonderfully but I'm not allowed to use it.
I've seen the source code and while it works quite well for small sequences, for longer sequences too much memory is used.
Quite normal since we are creating len(list)**k-length combinations.
My question is, is it possible to create an iterable generator that doesn't create the intermediate 'result' list?
I've been fiddling with this function and thinking about a recursive solution but couldn't come up with anything that solved my problem.

Code for reference:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
         result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
         yield tuple(prod)
```

Another approach:

```
def possible_combinations(sequence):
    for a in sequence:
        for b in sequence:
            yield(a,b)

for combo in possible_combinations('123'):
    print(combo)
```

With this code I'd have 3**2=9 results, where 3 is the length of the '123' string and 2 the k.
This approach would also work if k were equal to 2, however given that k dynamically changes , I'd need to have k 'for loops' and not only 2 'for loops'.

if k=3:

```
def possible_combinations(sequence):
    for a in sequence:
        for b in sequence:
            for c in sequence:
                 yield(a,b,c)

for combo in possible_combinations('123'):
    print(combo)
```

And now I'd have 3**k = 27 results.
If k were 4 another for loop would need to be added, like so:

```
def possible_combinations(sequence):
    for a in sequence:
        for b in sequence:
            for c in sequence:
                 for d in sequence:
                     yield(a,b,c,d)

for combo in possible_combinations('123'):
    print(combo)
```

And now I'd have 3**4=81 results

Comment: This is the default in  python 3. `>>> product('ABCD', repeat=2)`  returns
`<itertools.product object at 0x7fd52775dc18>`

Comment: That's not the source code for `itertools.product`; the docs only say it's *roughly equivalent to* that code.

Comment: thanks, this has clarified your question a lot. I now completely rewrote my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new info I'll completely rewrite my post. If you need to pick tuples of length `k` from a sequence `seq` then indeed the easiest solution would be to use recursion:

```
def k_sequence(seq, k, chosen = ()):
    if k == 0:
        yield chosen
    else:
        for i in seq:
            yield from k_sequence(seq, k-1, chosen + (i,))

for combo in k_sequence([1,2,3], 3):
    print(combo)
```

A few explanations:

- `yield from` is what you were probably looking for. It yields all the values it gets from the inner calls to the outer calls
- I worked with tuples because generally lists are mutable and you generally don't want that any inner/outer calls messes with lists from others. Although lists work here also, immutability generall goes better with recursion

**Update: Without recursion**

If, for any reason you would like to go without recursion (e.g. if k is very big and you would run into recursion or memory limits), you could do something like this: Let's say `seq=[1,2,3]` `k=3` you could imagine you have three pointers all pointing to the first one, `1` in the list, then you would move the first pointer down the list until you reach the end, then you would put the pointer back to zero and move the second pointer to the next element, and so on.

```
def k_sequence(seq, k):
    pointers = [0] * k
    while True:
        yield tuple(seq[i] for i in pointers)
        p = 0
        pointers[p] += 1
        while pointers[p] == len(seq):
            pointers[p] = 0
            p += 1
            if p == len(seq):
                return
            pointers[p] += 1

for combo in k_sequence([1,2,3], 3):
    print(combo)
```

Comment: Yes, that code works, however  the number of for loops needs to be equal to k-length. I tried doing something recursive but am having a hard time doing so.

Comment: what do you mean with "the number of loops needs to be equal to k-length"? Is k the length of the list? There will be more than k possible pairs from the list (it's `k*(k-1)/2`), so how can you only loop k times?

Comment: say that your sequence is '123', your code will give me 3^(number of loops)= 9 results
Imagine however that I want 3^k results. In order to do this I need to dynamically change the number of loops...
So for example if k=3 I'd have 3^3 =27 results, for k=4 81 results and so forth.

Comment: Yes, my code is two nested loops, that means it's `O(n^2)`. I don't get where you're going. Can you maybe rephrase your question. It's not even clear to me if you're only looking for pairs or also maybe triples. And it's also not clear what should be the runtime of the script, etc..

Comment: maybe it's all clear in the question and it's just me not understanding.. if you can link to wikipedia articles or anything, that would help as well

Comment: My question was not very clear, I've edited it. See if you can understand it please.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: @PedroQueirós: glad that was it. I have also added an example without recursion :)